# Почему не работает xdebug?

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Установил `XDebug`-расширение для VSCode а также и сам `XDebug` согласно прилагаемой инструкции. Настроил. Все по инструкции. На выходе получаю такую картину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же я проверял включен ли отладчик - вот результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по идее после перехода в браузер и обновления странцы я должен был перейти автоматически в VSCode и остановиться на месте точки остановы. Вместо этого страница просто обновляется, а в `error.log` я получаю такую ошибку `[Wed Jan 03 16:43:36.319934 2024] [php:notice] [pid 3853] [client 127.0.0.1:45102] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).`

Вот конфиги в `php.ini`

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Сервер `Apache`

**Как заставить XDebug работать?**